# How to use Gecko Mouse gesture events?

Tags: dom, desktop-application, multi-touch, gesture-recognition, gecko

i'm developing a webGL Desktop app, and i'd like to provide a multi-touch interface.

It seems that the only solution concerning desktops is https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Mouse_gesture_events , but how do i include it in my javascript code? How do I call the gesture callback functions, what do i have to include?

I'm not used to web development and i'm still learning a lot, so forgive me if it's a dumb question.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How were you planning to trigger the multi-touch events on a desktop? Touchscreen? Magic Trackpad style input? If you’re going down that route then Gecko has [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Touch_events) that handle multi-touch fine.

The main problem with your original solution is summer up with this paragraph:

> **Note:** These gesture events are available to add-ons and other browser chrome code, but are never sent to regular web page content.

If you’re just building your app as a Fluid-style SSB then you’re not going to have these events available; you’d have to build your app as a browser extension to get into the correct security model.